# Suggestion for SQL distributed transactions via MSDTC

Tags: sql-server, msdtc

Currently we do not use MSDTC in our company. Our developers would like to start using MSDTC for Distributed Transactions within their applications.

Questions:

1. Is it okay to use MSDTC for SQL distributed transactions (there would be millions of transactions per day)?
2. What is the best practice to use it security wise?
3. Is there any other alternative to do the distributed transactions from the application?

Comment: Are you using AlwaysOn Availability Groups? If so then you would need to find something else as Microsoft do not support the use of DTC with AGs.

Comment: Thank you Paul.

No, we are not using AlwaysOn Availability Groups.